# Linq Select Results Generated Used Multiple Times

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a query that is pulling data from the database and also manufacturing data with other methods that is included in the result set.

```
var results = from mr in db.Material_Reqs
          join j in db.Jobs on mr.Job equals j.Job1
          where j.Top_Lvl_Job == topLevelJob
          select new
          {
              mr.Material,
              mr.Material_Req1,
              mr.Job,
              mr.Description,
              Lot = GetLotNumber(mr.Material),
              UnitCost = GetUnitCost(mr.Material, GetLotNumber(mr.Material))
          };
```

The Lot field is added by calling a function GetLotNumber and passing it the material field from the query. The UnitCost needs the generated field Lot to be calculated. Is there a technique to use the Lot filed in a method to generate the next field?

What I've shown works but is wasteful of time because it regenerated the same data twice for the Lot number.

How can I use the generated Lot field to pass to a method?

Comment: `What I've shown works` I'm impressed this works at all with the custom methods that are being translated to sql

Comment: @Jonesopolis, nothing special here, it is not translated to the SQL. Last `Select` just evaluated partially on the client. So every record will call `GetLotNumber` and `GetUnitCost` methods while reading other fields from DataReader.

Comment: "but is wasteful"... Do you have reasons to believe that calling `GetLotNumber` causes a significant performance hit? Have you measured? To quote Donald Knuth "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."

Comment: @JonasH, actually if under these functions `GetLotNumber` and `GetUnitCost` is hidden another requests to database - we have `3 * N + 1` query problem.

Comment: @JonasH, As I indicated I'm learning here. The given example causes an extra SQL Server select, maybe that's hurts in time and maybe not. If there is a better way I want to know so next time the the routine is expensive, there may be a way to not call it twice.

Comment: You might pre evalute it via a `let lot = GetLotNumber(mr.Material)` between the where and the select and then use the variable in the initializer of the anonymous class.

Comment: The let documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Comment: Whether these functions are translated depends on what they do, and whether they're translatable.  Ignoring the details of the actually GetLotNumber function, and assuming it's expensive for a non-database linked reason, then you could just leave UnitCost blank on the first pass and perform a second step on the clientside to calculate it: .AsEnumerable().ForEach(a => a.UnitCost =GetUnitCost(a.Material, a.Lot));

Answer (score 1):

Ralf has the answer, I never know about "let" before today, thank you!

```
var results = from mr in db.Material_Reqs
      join j in db.Jobs on mr.Job equals j.Job1
      where j.Top_Lvl_Job == topLevelJob
      let tmpLot = mr.Material
      select new
      {
          mr.Material,
          mr.Material_Req1,
          mr.Job,
          mr.Description,
          Lot = tmpLot,
          UnitCost = GetUnitCost(mr.Material, tmpLot)
      };
```

This opens a bunch of interesting combinations. Thank you to everyone for the assist!

Comment: Doesn't seem correct, it should be `tmpLot = GetLotNumber(mr.Material)`.